# Dynamically call a var inside string in function

Tags: python

I'm new to python, I have var (string) which is an *Xpath* query. I want to pass the variable *`i`* into the *Xpath* query. A simple example  below:

```
i = 0
self.var = 'li['+i+']'

def test(self):
  while(i<10):
   print self.var #  'li[0]', 'li[1]' ...
   i += 1
```

Comment: If you want to convert `i` to a string, you need to google "python convert number to string". **Edit**: the answer is `str(i)`.

Comment: @AndrasDeak, if they know what to google for they would not be asking the question. Also thanks for the downvote

Comment: NOOOOO NO EVAL. @Padraic I know, I'm telling them right now;) If it weren't for your anwer, I would've added the solution too myself. In a comment.

Comment: Since you have `self.var` I am guessing this is class code, but the value of self.val will be a string, and not what it may look like -- a list item

Comment: @AndrasDeak, telling someone to google something is not really helpful just as downvoting a correct answer.

Comment: @joelgoldstick, it is an xpath not a list

Comment: @PadraicCunningham you're right about the first half: I edited my comment to be informative. I disagree with the second half: downvotes are for *unhelpful* answers too. I don't think spoon-feeding askers is helpful, and I also tend to consider the effect of answers on the roomba. I'm not saying that all answers to beginner questions are spoon-feeding, but in this case that's what I feel.

Comment: @joelgoldstick exactly!

Comment: Do you have a list, `li`, that you want to access each element inside li or you just want a string to look like `li[1], li[2], li[3]...`? You can try `['li['+str(i)+']' for i in range(10)]` if the latter

Comment: @dawg anyway thanks, self.var = "li[{}]" work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to call *`str`* on the variable *`i`*, you cannot concatenate an int and a str:

```
 'li['+str(i)+']'
```

Or just use *str.format*, you can also pass use range and xpath indexing is also 1-based so you would start at 1:

```
 self.var = "li[{}]"
 def test(self):
    for i in range(1, 11):
       print self.var.format(i)
```

Or if using *lxml* for your Xpath queries you can use an  [Xpath variable](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html) like below:

```
 .xpath("li[$i]", i=i)
```

Comment: Why exactly was the answer down-voted? care to explain down-voter?

Comment: @Mr.goosberry I was hoping to pressure Padraic into deleting his answer [because of this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39301564/dynamically-call-a-var-inside-string-in-function#comment65937276_39301564). My main concern is that very basic questions should be deleted sooner than later, and that doesn't automatically happen with upvoted/accepted answers present. Now there's another answer around, and there's no chance for roomba to kick in, so I'm revoking my downvote.

Comment: self.var = "li[{}]" Thanks.

Comment: @AndrasDeak thank you for your argument. I appreciate someone who had reasons for downvoting, and doesn't  just do to do. And know that I understand your viewpoint, I agree that spoon-feeding users is a bad idea. My mistake for not reading his(MED's) question more careful and seeing what is really was asking.

Comment: Or `self.var = r'li[%d]'`, and when calling it: `print self.var%i`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list with the first string, the integer, and the second string.

```
i = 0
var = ['li[',i,']']

def test(var):    
    while(var[1]<10):
        print var[0]+str(var[1])+var[2]
        var[1] += 1

test(var)
```